# Behaviour of raw_input()

Tags: python, python-2.7, raw-input

I wanted to understand the behaviour of raw_input in the below code.
I know `num` will be string. 
Irrespective of whatever number i enter it always enter the `elif` part i.e. if num is 5, which should go to `if num<check:` part or if num is 10 which should go to `else` part. Every single time it is going to `elif`. I thought comparing STRING and INT might throw exception( I dont think so) but just in case, so I had included `try except` but as expected it did not throw any exception. But what puzzles me is why it is ALWAYS hitting `elif` even when the input given was 10, atleast in that case i was expecting output **Equal**

```
num = raw_input('enter a number')
check = 10
try:
    if num<check:
        print 'number entered %s is less'%num

    elif num>check:
        print 'number entered %s is greater'%num

    else:
        print 'Equal!!!'
    print 'END'
except Exception,e:
    print Exception,e
```

Please, PYTHON gurus, solve the Mystery :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How does Python compare string and int?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3270680/how-does-python-compare-string-and-int)

Answer (score 4):

`raw_input` returns a string. So use `int(raw_input())`.

And for how string and int comparsions work, look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3270680/how-does-python-compare-string-and-int).

Comment: That link has removed all my doubts/questions/confusions.Thanks for the link and well I knew about type casting num to int but just wanted to understand raw_input and I guess, using just `input()` would also solve my purpose.

Comment: Using just `input()` would be a security risk. There is a reason why the functionality of Python 2 `input` is gone in Python 3.

Answer (score 1):

See the [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3270689/225997).

Basically you're comparing apples and oranges.

```
>>> type(0) < type('10')
True
>>> 0 < '10'
True
>>> type(0) ; type('10')
<type 'int'>
<type 'str'>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Python 2.7:    
num = int(raw_input('enter a number:'))
Variable "num" will be of type str if raw_input is used.
type(num)>>str
or 
num = input("Enter a Number:")# only accept int values
type(num)>>int

Python 3.4 : 
num = input("Enter a Number:") will work ...
type(num)>>str
convert the variable "num" to int type(conversion can be done at time of  getting the user "input") :
num1 = int(num)
```