# Why is this simple code wrong?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
print("Hello there")
name=input("What is your name?")
print("Welcome to the some game, " + name + "!")
print("I'm going to ask you some basic questions so that we could work together")
age=input("Your age")
if age >= 14 and age < 41:
    print("K")
else:
    print("Sorry bruh")
print("Thanks")
```

keeps showing me "Sorry bruh" at the end when entered 15. Why? What's wrong?

Comment: ussing python 3 I get `TypeError: unorderable types: str() >= int()` and using python 2 I get no problem. (other then not being able to use a string name)

Comment: @Tadhg, you get no error but you get the wrong answer. Python 2 compares the _names_ of types when they are incompatible! (`"int" < "str"`)

Comment: @alexis no, on python 2 if you type in `15` for the age it prints out `K`, on python 3 it raises an error when trying to compare the str to int, so I am unable to reproduce '''showing me "Sorry bruh" at the end when entered 15.'''

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Behaviour of raw\_input()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17638087/behaviour-of-raw-input)

Comment: Oh no wait, you're right: On python 2, `input( )` will convert to `int`. But this is python 3-- obviously not the only problem with it.

Answer (score 4):

Cast your `input` to `int`:

```
age = int(input("Your age"))
```

You could add a `try-except`. Your condition should equally be evaluated on `or` not `and`

Answer (score 0):

Either you use Python3 and you need to cast with `int(input("Your age"))` or you use Python2 and then you need to use `raw_input` to read the name: `name=raw_input("What is your name?")`

Answer (score 0):

Ok , so you can try this code in python2.7 and it will work as you desired:

```
print("Hello there")
name=raw_input("What is your name?")
print("Welcome to the some game, " + name + "!")
print("I'm going to ask you some basic questions so that we could work together")
age=input("Your age")
if age >= 14 and age < 41:
    print("K")
else:
    print("Sorry bruh")
print("Thanks")
```